# Convert number to 5 digit string

Tags: php, design-patterns

I want to convert a number to a 5 character string. The string characters are a-z, A-Z and 0-9. Each combination of that code increments by "1"

I am not sure how to explain it, so I am going to give you an example.
For example

```
1 = aaaaa
26 = aaaaz
27 = aaaaA
52 = aaaaZ
53 = aaaa0
62 = aaaa9
63 = aaaba
89 = aaabz
90 = aaab0
```

So if I had number 1035, is there a way PHP can calculate the code for that?

Sorry my question is a little vague.

The reason I want to do this is because I don't want to to show my database primary key id, I want to show this base63 format.

Comment: Sure. What you have created is a custom base numbering system that goes a-zA-Z0-9. It's effectively a base 63 numbering system I suppose. Using numbers your example would show: 63 = 00010 The caveat is that a is serving as 1 AND 0 in your example. aaaaa = 1 where in a true re-based numbering system it would be _ _ _ _ a = 1.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. Do you have any resources so I can read more into this?

Comment: Convert your number to base 63 normally. Then convert each digit in the result to the ones you're using, using `strtr()`.

Comment: OP - read through this link and see if it makes more sense. http://betterexplained.com/articles/numbers-and-bases/ Base 2, 8 and 16 are commonly used so there are lots of examples out there.

Comment: From the FAQ: _Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results._ So try implementing this using the above hints, then come back with your code if you have a problem.

Comment: Your sequence is not logical

Comment: Why isn't it logical?

Comment: When you pass 62 to 63

Comment: Peter - this is what I mentioned in my first post that a represents 1 and 0. 0000a should be 1 but aaaaa is 1. Where 0 is some character representing a value for 0.

Comment: ^ Listen to @Barmar's comment, he's right, provided one does a left-pad with `a`'s (effectively `0`'s) (make it an answer maybe?). [**edit**:] Ah no, `a` is _both_ 1 & 0, this cannot coexist, unless you make `1` `aaaab`.

Comment: The right structure would be aaaaa = 0, aaaab = 1, and so on. That should solve the problem of using a for both 0 and 1.

Comment: Thanks all for clearing that up :) my next question is how would I go about converting "0" to "aaaaa" and "1" to aaaab?

Comment: Yes @ChrisRasco, it's not logical, I go back on my answer :)

Comment: It's not logical, since from 26 to 27 it is `z` -> `A` and from 89 to 90 it is `z` -> `0`

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks this is base 62 not 63?

Comment: @PeterStuart I assume `a` would be like leading zeros, but in that case shouldnt absolute `aaaaa` be 0? `aaaaa` being 1 is kind of nonsense here. Assuming its a base 63, sinse you are using a total of 63 symbols, the last symbol in the representation of 63 and all of its multiples should be the same as in 0, but it is not. Your sequence is ilogical.

Comment: The reason I wanted 1 = aaaaa is becuse 1 is going to be a primary key!

Comment: @PeterStuart Your first step will be to get this into a base 63 number and then convert it to the correct representation of your characters. The link I provided on base 16 or base 2 numbers should help a bit. Here's a another good link for you: http://rot47.net/base.html < This actually has a calc and code sample for exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could do something like this:

```
function custom_base_62($n)
{
    if ($n < 1)
        trigger_error('custom_base_62(): This silly system cannot represent zero.', E_USER_ERROR);

    $n -= 1;
    $symbols = array_merge(range('a', 'z'), range('A', 'Z'), range(0, 9));
    $r = '';

    while ($n)
    {
        $r = $symbols[$n % 62] . $r;
        $n = floor($n / 62);
    }

    return str_pad($r, 5, $symbols[0], STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

Comment: Would you still consider it silly because 0 isn't allowed in MySQL databases? And that's where the number is coming from?

Comment: We are discussing two different beasts. 1 is mathematically not the lowest positive integer value you can have, and this is relevant in base conversions. In the other hand, MySQL auto_increment columns will start with 1 to attribute identity to your rows, but they do can be zero if you force it. And in the same way zero-padding 1 would be 00001, the logical conversion of 1 in your base should be `aaaab`.

Comment: I'll alter your code here then to allow 0's :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea you can play with, not fully sure i understand your exact goal..

```
<?php

function Digit_to_char($s){

  $s1 = str_split($s);
  while(list($k,$v) = each($s1)){
    $s2[] = str_replace(range(0,9), array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","y","z"), $v);
  }

  return implode('',$s2);
}


echo Digit_to_char(12345); // prints bcdef

?>
```